# Wildcard SSL on domain with nginx redirects to www. regardless

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a server setup for SSL. Below are the 80 and 443 configs. Regardless of how we set up nginx the system automatically redirects the m.domain.com to www.m.domain.com.

Is anyone able to assist? I've tried numerous configurations and suggestions, but to no avail. nginx v1.6.2

**SSL**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/en/<domain>.com.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/en/<domain>.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    root /var/www/vhosts/m.<domain>.com/public;
    server_name m.<domain>.com api.<domain>.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/m.<domain>.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/m.<domain>.com-error.log;

    location / {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   LARAVEL_ENV             production;
    }
}
```

**NON SSL**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name m.<domain>.com api.<domain>.com;

    root /var/www/vhosts/m.<domain>.com/public;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/m.<domain>.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/m.<domain>.com-error.log;

    location / {
            index index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   LARAVEL_ENV             production;
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing via CURL shows... 
`curl -I https://m.domain.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 15:29:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.m.domain.com/`
as the response

Comment: Your application is most likely sending the redirect unless you have other `server` blocks. Check `index.php` and related application.

Comment: Thanks folks, but no joy. 

So the redirect is not happening at the application level. As I placed an info.php file on the server and it was never parsed and I ended up with the same redirect. So its happening at the server level.

I just cant see where...

Comment: OK, please then show the complete nginx configuration for your site.

Comment: Above is the config for the m. site as it stands. There are other vhosts on this domain, but all https requests appear to be getting answered by the default domain.com.conf file and then redirecting to www.<subdomain>.domain.com. Please see this one attached, both the SSL and NON-SSL configs are the same expect the urls...

Comment: I cant pass in the full conf file as this is too long for a post... **shurgs**. Heres an edited version...

`server {
 listen       80 default_server;
 autoindex on;
 server_name www.example.net blog.example.com;
 if ($host ~* blog.domain.com) {
         rewrite ^(.*)$  http://www.example.com/blog$1 permanent;
 }
 if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
        }
 client_max_body_size 30M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
 # Root proxy
 location / {
  <PHP Proxy stuff>
 }
}`

Comment: `server {
 listen 443;
 autoindex on;
 server_name www.example.com blog.example.com;
 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/en/example.com.cer;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/en/example.com.key;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 if ($host ~* blog.example.com) {
         rewrite ^(.*)$  http://www.example.com/blog$1 permanent;
 }
 if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent;
       }
 client_max_body_size 30M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
 # Root proxy
 location / {

 }
 # Site proxy
 location @public {
 }
}`

Comment: FYI I have already tried adding `if ($host !~* ^m\.) { rewrite ^(.*)$ http://www.$host$1 permanent; } ` above the non www check, but still it didn't get executed.

Comment: Edit your question and include the configuration there. It is too difficult to read otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I installed on test nginx and this working goods.

1. Check yours PHP scripts. You can add script with only phpinfo(); and save this as phpinfo.php (with php tags) and check:
   `https://m.domain.com/phpinfo.php`
2. When this not working check your DNS. Add to you /etc/hosts:
    
   And check.
3. Check your htaccess file (if you have).

My curl respond:

```
curl -I https://m.domain.com --insecure # insecure because I don`t have cert
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sat, 22 Apr 2017 22:55:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 42
Last-Modified: Sat, 22 Apr 2017 22:50:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "58fbde21-2a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

My test nginx configuration:

**SSL**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.com.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.com.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    root /var/www/html/;
    server_name m.domain.com api.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/m.domain.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/m.domain.com-error.log;

    location / {
            index index.php index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
}
```

**NoSSL:**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name m.domain.com api.domain.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/m.domain.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/m.domain.com-error.log;

    location / {
            index index.php index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks folks, but no joy. 

So the redirect is not happening at the application level. As I placed an info.php file on the server and it was never parsed and I ended up with the same redirect. So its happening at the server level.

I just cant see where...

Comment: Can you add nginx logs ?

Comment: The logs show nothing other than standard responses we see from CURL requests in the access logs and this doesn't generate any errors.

Comment: Change you root folder to others empty folder for test - restart nginx - than add this phpinfo file, and check. When m.domain.com redirect check api.domain.com.

Comment: This is a live production site, so no...

Comment: api.domain.com redirect to www.api.domain.com ?

Comment: No api.domain.com doesnt redirect

Comment: SSL works 100% on www.domain.com